# Centering table caption

Tags: tables, positioning

I created a table in a 2-column paper to fit just on 1 column. 
Everything is okay, except for the table caption position. 
When I dont use `tabularx` the table caption position is good.

I tried the customization with the `caption` package:

```
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
```

but it did not help and it changed the caption format.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e,bm,newtxmath} % new packages
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htbp]
%\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{System variables dependencies}\label{tab1}
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{@{} l *{4}{Y} @{}}
\toprule
System variables &  $x_{4}$ & $x_{5}$ & $x_{6}$\\
\cmidrule(l){2-2} \cmidrule(l){3-3} \cmidrule(l){4-4} 
\addlinespace
Structural dependencies & $f(x_{4})=x_{4}$ & 
$f(x_{5})=x_{4}\times x_{4}$   & $f(x_{6})=x_{5}/x_{4}$ \\
\addlinespace
Operational dependencies & n/a & n/a & $x_{4}>0$  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Table obtained :[image]

Comment: Your code working well, please increase the number of columns and then check...

Comment: I try to increase the number of columns but it don't change anything. The caption is always centered as it was a 2-column width table.

Comment: Use `table` instead of `table*` in combination with `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}`. With these changes table and caption will fit into one column. Also, 3 `Y` type columns should be sufficient for your table (`*{3}{Y}`).

Comment: Unrelated but to save some space, you could also go for something like `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\caption{System variables dependencies}\label{tab1}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X ccc@{}}` in order to avoid linebreaks in the cells.

Comment: Thanks @leandriis, it solves the problem for the caption, I have to change  `0.5\linewidth ` by `\linewidth`. I don't why, but it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table's caption *is* centered at present. It's the `tabularx` environment that isn't centered. (It's typeset flush-left.)

I suggest you insert a `\centering` directive before the start of the `tabularx` environment.

There's actually no compelling need here for a `tabularx` environment, especially as the result of the automatic line breaking isn't great. (If you replaced `0.5\linewidth` with `\columnwidth`, you could stick the resulting table into a single column.) Using a plain `tabular` environment seems to be preferable if you want the table to span both columns.

The following screenshot shows the result of using a `tabularx` and a `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
%% keeping the preamble to an absolute minimum:
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,newtxmath} 
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering

\caption{System variables dependencies --- Take 1}
\label{tab1}
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{@{} l *{3}{Y} @{}}
\toprule
System variables &  $x_{4}$ & $x_{5}$ & $x_{6}$\\
\cmidrule(l){2-2} \cmidrule(l){3-3} \cmidrule(l){4-4}
\addlinespace
Structural dependencies & $f(x_{4})=x_{4}$ &
$f(x_{5})=x_{4}\times x_{4}$   & $f(x_{6})=x_{5}/x_{4}$ \\
\addlinespace
Operational dependencies & n/a & n/a & $x_{4}>0$  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip\bigskip
\caption{System variables dependencies --- Take 2}
\label{tab2}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l ccc @{}}
\toprule
System variables &  $x_{4}$ & $x_{5}$ & $x_{6}$\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(l){4-4}
Structural dependencies & $f(x_{4})=x_{4}$ &
$f(x_{5})=x_{4}\times x_{4}$   & $f(x_{6})=x_{5}/x_{4}$ \\
\addlinespace
Operational dependencies & n/a & n/a & $x_{4}>0$  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually I want the table to span just on column.

Comment: @nicope13 — In that case you shouldn’t be using a `table*` environment. You should be using a `tabke` environment instead.